# How to show only last 3 months in morris chart in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, morris.js

I have been facing a problem in my project. I want to how last 3 months activity in my morris chart. But don't know how to achieve this.

Here is what I got:

[image]

In this I got August multiple times. What I want is only 3 months: August, September, October.

Here is what I tried:

```
public function sales() {
    $company = Auth::guard('company')->user()->id;
    $date = Carbon::now();
    $currentmonth = Order::where([['company_id', $company], ['status', '<>', 0]])->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date->copy()->startOfMonth())->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date->copy()->endOfMonth())->get();
    $lastmonth = Order::where([['company_id', $company], ['status', '<>', 0]])->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date->copy()->startOfMonth()->subMonth())->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date->copy()->endOfMonth()->subMonth())->get();
    $anothermonth = Order::where([['company_id', $company], ['status', '<>', 0]])->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $date->copy()->startOfMonth()->subMonths(2))->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $date->copy()->endOfMonth()->subMonths(2))->get();

    $data = [
        [ 'year'=> $date->year . '-' . $date->copy()->startOfMonth()->subMonths(2)->format('m'), 'value'=> $anothermonth->sum('price') ],
        [ 'year'=> $date->year . '-' . $date->copy()->startOfMonth()->subMonth()->format('m'), 'value'=> $lastmonth->sum('price') ],
        [ 'year'=> $date->year . '-' . $date->copy()->format('m'), 'value'=> $currentmonth->sum('price') ],
    ];

    $json = json_encode($data);

    return view('company.dashboard.sales', compact('json'));
}
```

And my JavaScript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var months = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];

var area = new Morris.Area({
    element: 'revenue-chart',
    resize: true,
    data: {!! $json !!},
    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['value'],
    lineColors: ['#75a5c1'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    xLabelFormat: function(x) { // <--- x.getMonth() returns valid index
        var month = months[x.getMonth()];
        return month;
      },
      dateFormat: function(x) {
        var month = months[new Date(x).getMonth()];
        return month;
    },
});
</script>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `parseTime` parameter of your Morris Area to `false`:

```
parseTime: false
```

And set the `xLabelFormat` like this:

```
 xLabelFormat: function (x) {
     return months[parseInt(x.label.slice(5))];
 }
```

Please try the following snippet:

```js
var data = [
  { year: '2018-08', value: 0 },
  { year: '2018-09', value: 5 },
  { year: '2018-10', value: 10 }];

var months = ["JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];

var lineGraph = Morris.Area({
    element: 'revenue-chart',
    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['value'],
    lineColors: ['#75a5c1'],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    labels: ['Sales'],
    data: data,
    resize: true,
    xLabelAngle: 90,
    parseTime: false,
    xLabelFormat: function (x) {
        return months[parseInt(x.label.slice(5))];
    }
});

$('svg').height(350);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="revenue-chart"></div>
```

Comment: If I set parse time false then It does not show month name. It show data 2018-08 format

Comment: When I add your code It shown Only September, October. August not shown. Thank You for your help

Comment: Yes August is there. It's just hidden. You can try like in my snippet to set the `xLabelAngle` to rotate the labels. You can also set the svg height to the appropriate value if there's still a problem with the x labels.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.